# Can't ssh into freshly installed Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, vmware-workstation

So I just installed a bare Ubuntu Server 20.04 in VMWare using bridged networking. It has an IP address, it has internet, I can ping websites, I can update and install new packages, I can even SSH into the server using the IP address from the server.

But when I try to use Putty to connect from my host machine, Windows 10, it sits forever and then times out. If I try to do telnet it prints out `Could not open connection to the host, on port 22: Connect failed`

So it's like it there on the network and has access to the internet and can connect to itself using the IP given by DHCP but any program outside of the server acts like the server isn't even there. At this point I have no clue what's going on.

I'm trying to ssh to `192.168.1.71` port 22 which is the IP from `ip a` and like I said I can't telnet to it either.

ServerFault won't let me upload images and I don't have a way to copy the text so I hope I typed everything correctly blow, apologies if I made a slight typo and missed it:

```
root@####:~# ip a 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default glen 1000 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo 
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default glen 1000 
    link/ether 00:0c:29:db:1c:d9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
    inet 192.168.1.71/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic ens33 
        valid_lft 257299sec preferred_lft 257299sec
    inet6 2600:6c5d:5900:331e::124/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
        valid_lft 567152sec preferred_lft 567152sec 
    inet6 2600:6c5d:5900:331e:20c:29ff:fedb:1cd9/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
        valid_lft 569021sec preferred_lft 569021sec 
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fedb:1cd9/64 scope link 
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@####:~#
```

```
root####:~# service sshd status
• ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded [/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled] 
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-05-18 19:49:34 UTC; 50min ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
            man:sshd_config(5)
     Process: 861 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) 
   Main PID: 877 (sshd)
     Tasks: 1 (limit: 2248)
     Memory: 3.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
            L-877 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups

May 18 19:49:34 #### systemd[1]:Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
May 18 19:49:34 #### sshd[877]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
May 18 19:49:34 #### systemd[1]:Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
root@####:~#
```

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Port 22
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ChallengeResponseAuthentification no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
PasswordAuthentification yes
```

This is what happens when I ping the IP, I get a reply back from a different IP saying it's unreachable.

```
Pinging 192.168.1.71 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.68: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.68: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.68: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.68: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.71:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

Comment: you should add tags your question with VMware and Workstation just to cover all bases. I don't have access to a WIndows laptop now, I have VirtualBox and there I install one vmnic in bridged mode and one in NATted mode. The bridged give me Internet access, while the NATted give me local access from my laptop. I can check tomorrow on Workstation. Can you ping the IP from your host? Can you try to ssh from a second VM also having a bridged vmnic.

Comment: @Zina thanks, I replaced one of the tags for vmware. When I ping the IP `192.168.1.71` I get a reply back `Reply from 192.168.1.68: Destination host unreachable.` `192.168.1.68` is my host computer, Windows 10. Why is my computer intercepting the ping an saying it's unreachable. The ping says there's no packet loss and that's because my computer intercepted all the pings. --- I updated my answer.

Comment: @Zina I got it working by disabling ipv6, but why did I have to disable ipv6. Also it keeps getting re-enabled on boot despite me having it in /etc/sysctl.conf. I don't understand why ipv6 caused the outside network top just not be able to communicate with the server but as I said the solution was simply to disable it within Ubuntu.

Comment: Nevermind, the connection happens but it randomly cuts out and drops. I often get maybe a minute before it happens. ---- I give up, I'll just open a DO server as something is wrong somewhere. It's either my router, VM Ware, Ubuntu, my computer,  something in some networking. I have a lot of stuff to do today and the last thing I want to do is spend a week trying to tackle networking problems. I'll just open a dev server on DO and proceed on to make this all much quicker.

Comment: I'm adding a "me too" here for the OP and posterity. I upgraded a few Ubuntu v18 systems to 20 and one of them randomly stops accepting SSH and ping. sysctl.conf and sshd_config have not been manually modified (or at all from what I can tell right now). Netstat shows ssh is listening. If I reboot, I can connect. If I just execute 'dhclient' with no options, it starts working again. I got that random clue from this 2018 thread https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2389945. I'll post back if I solve this but I hope it's a general v20 thing that will be patched.